# Is it the right way to process a PIL image in pytorch?

Tags: image, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I want to train a deep model from .png images by using Pytorch. I'm using a pre-trained model on ImageNet so I need to normalize images before feeding them to the network, but when I look at the result of the transform I see there are some values more than 1 and some less than -1. I'm wondering shouldn't they all be in [-1, 1] range? Am I doing it in the right way?
There is my code:

```
normalize = transforms.Normalize(
mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
transforms.ToTensor(),
normalize])

x = Image.open("path/to/the/file").convert('RGB')
x = self.transform(x) # I feed the network by x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct but `mean` and `std` are not calculated based on your data, rather you've taken those values from `ImageNet` dataset.

There will be some images which are out of `[-1, 1]` range as **they weren't part of the `mean` and `std` calculations in the first place** and it's expected during test. Also there are images outside this range as it changes mean and standard deviation to `0` and `1` respectively, hence there are samples which are outside this range.

If you wish to fine-tune your neural network you should calculate per-channel `mean` and `std` and input those values instead (though it might not make a large difference, depending on dataset and how many images you have).

Comment: Thanks Szymon, actually I'm following this tutorial to doing the transfer learning:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html , but in this tutorial the Imagenet mean and std is used and the mean and std of the new dataset weren't be used, so I'm confused now should I used ImageNet mean and std or calculate my own?

Comment: @PouyaAhmadvand In this case you are better off leaving ImageNet `mean` and `std` as bees and ants are closely related classes to the ones you can observe on ImageNet. It's fine if training isn't perfectly within `[-1, 1]` range.

Comment: Also even in ImageNet dividing by mean and standard deviation doesn't put the data in the range [-1, 1]. It makes the data have mean 0 and standard deviation of 1. Standard deviation of one does not imply that the maximum deviation <= 1.